# if time exceeds x minutes

Tags: python, time

im new to python and have a loop that pulls data from a json. i have set variables with if and else statements so when the variables match, it sends a notification. however, i would like add another if statement within the if so it displays the data in the window but the other if time exceed 5 minutes, send notification.

i tried to set something like

```
    import time
    time = time.gmtime().tm_min
    while True:
       if price <= buy:
          print ("BUY!")
          if time > timeout:
             send message code
             timeout = time.gmtime().tm_min + 1
                if timeout > 59:
                timeout = 00
```

since the script is running on a loop, i think the time has to keep updating. once the if statements are triggered, send a message and add 5 minutes to the time variable so that on the next loop if the statement is true, dont run if the time hasnt exceeded 5 minutes. i say 5 minutes but in the actual code i have 1 minute for 2 reasons. the first reason is because the first if statement doesnt last that long. after about 30minutes it goes further away from the price. the 2nd reason is because i dont know how to wrap around in python after 59 in time :P.

Comment: Please give a working example with correct indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from time import perf_counter

while True:
    start_time = perf_counter() + 300  # Set limit to 5 minutes (60 seconds * 5)

    if price <= buy:
        print ("BUY!")

    if perf_counter() > start_time:
        #send message code
```

Comment: works perfectly as i needed! i had to make a change tho. since its on a loop, it was always updating the start_time = perf_counter() so it never reached. by moving start_time = perf_counter()  above the while true: and adding start_time = perf_counter() + 300 after #send message code. thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is code which prints "BUY" every time the price is above the threshold, and sends a notification if no notifications have been sent in the previous 60 seconds.

```
import time
import random

def get_price():
    return random.random()

buy = 0.2  # Threshold price for buying
notification_time = 0   # This initial value ensures that the first notification is sent.
while True:
    if get_price() <= buy:
        print ("BUY!")
        if time.time()-notification_time > 60:
            notification_time = time.time()
            print("Sending notification")
    time.sleep(1)   # Wait 1 second before starting the next loop
```

Especially in python, you want to avoid doing stuff manually, like you do by taking the tm_min from the time object. You can usually get better results by using the existing libraries, such as subtraction between two timestamps.

Comment: i havent made a working code yet basically cant figure out how to avoid doing a timeout so that way i can still see the updates in the window live every second except after the notification is sent dont send another for x minutes.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I think I was now able to update my answer to answer you original question.