# How to interrupt the load command if time loading this file exceeds X seconds in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, load, interrupt, exit

I am trying to crawl some URLs and check for some points.
For this I am looping through a list of URLs.
This list does contain some URLs (I found one yet) that take extremely long to load.
My problem is now that I want to interrupt the load command if the command takes more than 60 seconds to load one URL and skip to the next URL.

The URL causing the problem is:
https://www.d1xz.net/astro/qinggan/art239417.aspx

When trying it in the browser it also renders the page only after some time.

Currently I am going with this line:
`try: res = br.open(url)`

But it won't stop unless there is a mistake (I had it running for more than 5 minutes before I quit the script at exactly this line by hand).

I found this post here on Stackoverflow: [if time exceeds x minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430355/if-time-exceeds-x-minutes) but it checks in between commands - not interrupting one command.

Has anyone had something similar and found a solution?
Or anyone having an idea in which direction to look for answers?

Thank you

Comment: a solution I am looking for is something like "give a max amount of seconds for a single command to execute - when exceeded to stop the command with an error message I can process"

Comment: No solution but a topic I might have to look into, to solve my problem (probably not the solution I was looking for - but a solution to keep the code running) is looking into multi threads